# How to convert encoding from 870 to 1250 in C#

Tags: c#, encoding

I am struggling with encoding convertion from 870 to 1250. I want to read a file in binary mode in chunks and then convert them to CP1250. So far I've prepared the code as below, but it doesn't support the less popular encoding ( I also installed a nuget package (System.Text.Encoding), but don't know, how to use it).

```
Encoding eIBM870 = Encoding.GetEncoding(870);
Encoding eCP1250 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1250);

FileStream fInput = File.OpenRead(fileInput.Text);
BinaryReader binReader = new BinaryReader(fInput);
byte[] bytes = binReader.ReadBytes(50);  //e.g. 50 bytes

byte[] converted = Encoding.Convert(eIBM870, eCP1250, bytes);

String output = eCP1250.GetString(converted);
```

So, I kindly ask for help.

Comment: If you use **.Net Core** call  `Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);` before using Windows code pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use *.Net Core* (not *.Net Framework*) call

```
Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
```

For instance

```
// Let .Net use platform specific code pages ("support the less popular encoding")
Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);

Encoding eIBM870 = Encoding.GetEncoding(870);
Encoding eCP1250 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1250);

// using : don't forget do Dispose reader (and stream)
using BinaryReader binReader = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(fileInput.Text));

byte[] bytes = binReader.ReadBytes(50); 

byte[] converted = Encoding.Convert(eIBM870, eCP1250, bytes);

String output = eCP1250.GetString(converted);
```

Please note, that working with string(s) is often a better option (some encoding are multibytes, so reading `50` can read an *invalid* string):

```
Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);

Encoding eIBM870 = Encoding.GetEncoding(870);
Encoding eCP1250 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1250);

using StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileInput.Text, eIBM870);

string output = reader.ReadLine();

byte[] converted = eCP1250.GetBytes(output);
```